# Finding the shortest path in a maze graph using adjacency matrix

Tags: java, graph, shortest-path, maze

I have some troubles with solving of a particular problem that is to find the shortest path in the maze graph. Probably, I'm stucked because of the fact that the maze is initialized by a four dimensional array like 
`adjacent = new boolean[height][width][height][width];` 
The first and second pair of indices specify a location in the graph in row/column formation. The graph looks like this:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXX
..........X.X
X.XXX.XXX.X.X
X.X.X...X.X.X
X.X.XXX.XXX.X
X...X.....X..
XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

The ArrayList must hold the locations of the vertices in the path, in order from start to end inclusive.

I've already written the constructor and connection method; however, I have trouble with the finding shortest path method.
Here is the example of how I create the maze graph:

```
final int edges[][] = {{1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 2, 1}, 
                {1, 2, 1, 3}, {1, 3, 1, 4}, {1, 4, 1, 5}, {1, 5, 1, 6}, 
                {1, 5, 2, 5}, {1, 6, 1, 7}, {1, 7, 1, 8}, {1, 8, 1, 9}, 
                {1, 9, 2, 9}, {1, 11, 2, 11}, {2, 1, 3, 1}, {2, 5, 3, 5}, 
                {2, 9, 3, 9}, {2, 11, 3, 11}, {3, 1, 4, 1}, {3, 3, 4, 3}, 
                {3, 5, 3, 6}, {3, 6, 3, 7}, {3, 7, 4, 7}, {3, 11, 4, 11}, 
                {4, 1, 5, 1}, {4, 3, 5, 3}, {4, 7, 5, 7}, {4, 11, 5, 11}, 
                {5, 1, 5, 2}, {5, 2, 5, 3}, {5, 5, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 5, 7}, 
                {5, 7, 5, 8}, {5, 8, 5, 9}, {5, 11, 5, 12}};

        MazeGraph maze = new MazeGraph(13, 7); 

        for (int[] edge : edges) 
            maze.connect(new Location(edge[0], edge[1]), new Location(edge[2], edge[3]));
```

Comment: Have you heard of *Dijkstra's algorithm*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this

```
adjacent = new boolean[height][width][height][width];
```

contradicts with this:

> The first and second pair of indices specify a location in the graph
> in row/column formation.

It is column/row, not row/column.

[Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) should be implemented for your matrix. Quote:

> Let the node at which we are starting be called the initial node. Let
> the distance of node Y be the distance from the initial node to Y.
> Dijkstra's algorithm will assign some initial distance values and will
> try to improve them step by step.
>
> 1. Assign to every node a tentative distance value: set it to zero for
>    our initial node and to infinity for all other nodes.
> 2. Set the initial node as current. Mark all other nodes unvisited. Create a set of all the unvisited nodes called the unvisited set.
> 3. For the current node, consider all of its unvisited neighbors and calculate their tentative distances. Compare the newly calculated
>    tentative distance to the current assigned value and assign the
>    smaller one. For example, if the current node A is marked with a
>    distance of 6, and the edge connecting it with a neighbor B has length
>    2, then the distance to B (through A) will be 6 + 2 = 8. If B was
>    previously marked with a distance greater than 8 then change it to 8.
>    Otherwise, keep the current value.
> 4. When we are done considering all of the neighbors of the current node, mark the current node as visited and remove it from the
>    unvisited set. A visited node will never be checked again.
> 5. If the destination node has been marked visited (when planning a route between two specific nodes) or if the smallest tentative
>    distance among the nodes in the unvisited set is infinity (when
>    planning a complete traversal; occurs when there is no connection
>    between the initial node and remaining unvisited nodes), then stop.
>    The algorithm has finished.
> 6. Otherwise, select the unvisited node that is marked with the smallest tentative distance, set it as the new "current node", and go
>    back to step 3.